# What are the scope restrictions for setting shopt extglob. and other options?

Tags: bash, shopt

My non-interactive bash shell has `extglob off`. I would like to turn it on in the statement immediately before a command, but I have noticed that when `shopt -s extglob` is within an `if .. then .. else` block, it somehow does not register.

The following *extglob-dependant* command is not valid: `syntax error near unexpected token '('`.

Where can `extglob` be set, and why is there a restriction, at all? Does this apply to other options?  ... *GNU bash 4.1.5*

This works:

```
shopt -s extglob
if true ;then
    touch a.bcd; ls a.@(bcd)
fi
```

This fails:

```
if true ;then
    shopt -s extglob
    touch a.bcd; ls a.@(bcd)
fi
... line 17: syntax error near unexpected token `('
... line 17: `touch a.bcd; ls a.@(bcd)'
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Not sure if there is a more authoritative source (ie. man page / official documentation) on this issue, but I found a site which explains this behavior: http://mywiki.wooledge.org/glob

> Because the extglob option changes the way certain characters are parsed, it is necessary to have a newline (not just a semicolon) between the shopt command and any subsequent commands that use extended globs. Likewise, you cannot put shopt -s extglob inside a statement block that uses extended globs, because the block as a whole must be parsed when it's defined; the shopt command won't take effect until the block is evaluated, at which point it's too late. In fact as bash parses the entire statement block before evaluating any of it, you need to set extglob outside of the outermost block.

Comment: Thanks. The *wooledge* link covers it quite well. I suppoes it had to be impemented that way because of some legacy issues.

Comment: @Peter.O I would say that it's that way because bash's parser is wonky. Of course, I'm a dirty-mouthed zsh user, except that I seem to remember this is the official reason given on the bash mailing list. Bash has a lot of similar parsing issues, such as `alias e=echo; e hello` not working: the alias definition only takes place on the next newline.

Comment: That's interesting, thanks... One day, I'll get around ot looking at zsh. It seems to have all the bells and whistles; very compact ones.