# Shell parameter expansion on command line does not work in bash script

Tags: bash, shell-script

Consider the following [GNU shell parameter expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion) on a bash command line, which is [explained here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66351936/2192488):

```bsh
$ a='hello world    example'

$ echo ${a//+( )/_}
hello_world_example
```

However, that very same parameter expansion no longer works in a bash script.

```bsh
# !/usr/bin/env bash
a='hello world    example'
echo "${a//+( )/_}"
```

It results in the unaltered string:

```
hello world    example
```

I did already learn from a simpler parameter expansion that the double quotes `" "` after the `echo` command are required, although I do not know why.

However, what more needs to be done for this particular parameter expansion to work in a bash script? And why?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`+(...)` is part of [extended globs](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Pattern-Matching.html), you need to enable them explicitly with `shopt -s extglob`.

If it works in your interactive shell, you probably have `shopt -s extglob` in one of the shell's startup files, like `bashrc`. But a regular non-interactive shell doesn't read those, so any settings there won't take effect, you need to put it explicitly in the script. Preferably on a line of its own, because there are some quirks with how it changes the workings of the parser, see:  [What are the scope restrictions for setting shopt extglob. and other options?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/45957/170373)

Comment: Does that `shopt -s extglob` go in the script or in `.bashrc`?

Comment: @SergeStroobandt: No you would put it in your script.

Comment: And why are the double quotes required in the script but not on the command line?

Comment: @SergeStroobandt, in the script. You probably have it `.bashrc` or such already if it works in an interactive shell.

Comment: @SergeStroobandt, double quotes do a different thing, try e.g. `a=abbd; echo "${a//b/ }"` with and without quotes and see http://mywiki.wooledge.org/WordSplitting