# function exported from .bashrc giving unexpected token for case pattern

Tags: wildcards, case

I am using Ubuntu 18.04 LTS with Gnu Bash 5.

Am getting the following error

```
/bin/bash: printm: line 56: syntax error near unexpected token `('
/bin/bash: printm: line 56: ` +([[:digit:]]))'
/bin/bash: error importing function definition for `printm'
```

The function is exported from my .bashrc. Was running `make` whilst installing `awk` and the error popped out. But if I test the function, it is behaving without problems.

Thought that I might be missing ;; at the end of a pattern. Something else must be happening.

There has been the suggestion of using

```
shopt -s extglob
```

But it's use has not resolved the problem

Here is the code

```
printm ()
{
 local sgr=$(tput sgr0)
 local blu=$(tput bold)$(tput setaf 39)
 local grn=$(tput bold)$(tput setaf 46)
 local cyn=$(tput bold)$(tput setaf 51)
 local red=$(tput bold)$(tput setaf 196)
 local mgn=$(tput bold)$(tput setaf 201)
 local org=$(tput bold)$(tput setaf 208)

 local  captr=0  arg=""
 local  opts=""  shortopts=""  longopts=""
 local  vb=1  ctp=""  cn=0  nl=0
  
 captr=0
 for arg in "$@"; do
   if [[ "$arg" == "-v" ]]; then
     captr=1
     continue
   elif (( captr == 1 )); then
     [[ "$arg" =~ ^[[:digit:]]+$ ]] && vb="$arg"
     captr=0 
   fi
 done

 shortopts="Vuhv::H::w::e::"
 shortopts="${shortopts}n::,l::,b,g,c,r,m,o"

 longopts="version,usage,help,verbosity::"
 longopts="${longopts},blu,grn,cyn,red,mgn,org"
 longopts="${longopts},heading::,warning::,error::"

 opts=$( getopt -o "$shortopts" -l "$longopts" -n "${0##*/}" -- "$@" )

 getopt_errcode=$?
 if (( getopt_errcode >= 1 )); then
   printf '%s%s%s\n' $red "Catched getopt_errcode" $sgr
 fi
 
 eval "set -- $opts"
 while (( $# > 0 )); do
   case $1 in
     ("-V"|"--version")
       local -r date="V01 2021 Jul 21 Wk27" 
       printf "%s\n\n" "$date"
       return
       ;;
     ("-u"|"--usage")
       printf '%s\n' "-V, --version, -u, --usage, -h, --help"
       return
       ;;
     ("-h"|"--help")
       return
       ;;
     ("-v"|"--verbosity")
       case "$2" in
         (+([[:digit:]])) vb="$2" ; shift 2 ;;
         (*)              vb=2 ; shift 2 ;;
       esac
       ;;
     ("-n")
       case "$2" in
         (+([[:digit:]])) cn="$2" ; shift 2 ;;
         (*)              cn=208 ; shift 2 ;;
       esac
       nl=1 ; ctp=$(tput bold)$(tput setaf $cn)
       ;;
     ("-l")
       case "$2" in
         (+([[:digit:]])) nl="$2"; shift 2 ;;
         (*)              nl=1 ; shift 2 ;;
       esac
       ;;
     ("-b"|"--blu") ctp="$blu" ; shift ;;
     ("-g"|"--grn") ctp="$grn" ; shift ;;
     ("-c"|"--cyn") ctp="$cyn" ; shift ;;
     ("-r"|"--red") ctp="$red" ; shift ;;
     ("-m"|"--mgn") ctp="$mgn" ; shift ;;
     ("-o"|"--org") ctp="$org" ; shift ;;
     ("-H"|"--heading")
       ctp="$mgn"
       case "$2" in
         (+([[:digit:]]))  nl="$2" ; shift 2 ;;
         (*)               nl=1    ; shift 2 ;;
       esac
       ;;
     ("-w"|"--warning")
       ctp="$blu"
       case "$2" in
         (+([[:digit:]]))  nl="$2" ; shift 2 ;;
         (*)               nl=1    ; shift 2 ;;
       esac
       ;;
     ("-e"|"--error")
       ctp="$red"
       case "$2" in
         (+([[:digit:]]))  nl="$2" ; shift 2 ;;
         (*)               nl=1    ; shift 2 ;;
       esac
       ;;
     ("--") shift ; break ;;
     (*) opt_error=1 ; break ;;
   esac
 done
}
```

Comment: Typically a .bashrc starts off with a test to see if the shell is being invoked interactivly, and if not it returns. Could you put your function after such a test to avoid the problem?

Comment: What would I need to do?

Comment: The error suggests that the `extglob` shell option is not enabled

Comment: @steeldriver Would that go inside the `function` or in the `.bashrc`?  I have a file with my special function in it, which I source from my bashrc.

Comment: @Dilna, you could probably just enable extglob globally at the beginning of your `.bashrc`, the cases where it would cause issues are relatively rare, see: [Is it dangerous to always have extglob on?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/276911/170373). Of course you could also set it in the function to make sure, or even check the current value and put it back... e.g. something like `local extglob=-u; if shopt -q extglob; then extglob=-s; fi; shopt -s extglob; [do something with extglob set]; shopt "$extglob" extglob;`

Comment: (but [it needs to be set on a line of its own](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/45957/170373))

Comment: Have included `shopt -s extglob` at the beginning of the script, but the error is still showing up.

Comment: Always paste your script into `https://shellcheck.net`, a syntax checker, or install `shellcheck` locally. Make using `shellcheck` part of your development process.

Comment: Have used `set -x` to turn debugging on, but I am not getting additional information.  Have looked at `https://shellcheck.net` although I found it too prescriptive on what constructs one should use.  It's all about what one is trying to do.

Comment: Any ideas why it could be clogging up on pattern `(+([[:digit:]]))` within case, apart from `shopt -s extglob`?

Comment: Can one use cases like what I have done enclosed within `( )`, i.e. `case "$2" in
( +([[:digit:]]) )` ?  I want to check whether the value in `$2` is numerically valid (should be from 1 to 255) for 256 colours provided by `terminfo`.